# How to create an SPSite object with the token from the SSP app pool user in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

How to create an SPSite object with the token from the SSP app pool user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is to elevate the current context to the highest level.

You can achieve this by [Running Commands with Elevated Privileges in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466220%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
See also [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

There shouldn't be a need to mess with tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way, if it's a single operation, would be to launch a command prompt with the identity of that application pool account (why the SSP one ?) and launch a stsadm -o createsite ... command. Your site will thus be created assuming that the SSP account has enough right to do so (which I guess will be the case, a farm account might be relevant at that level)

Do you want to allow specific user to spawn new site collection from another site collection ? A self service site creation portal might be better in that case.

Kindly.